# How to importing css to pdf, cordova-pdf-generator?

Tags: javascript, cordova-plugins

Good afternoon, 
I am working with this plugin and guiding me with the documentation to use css file, I have the following error ReferenceError: _ is not defined

```
var opts = {
            documentSize: "A4",
            landscape: "portrait",
            type: "share",
            fileName: 'my-pdf.pdf'
        }
        console.log(device.platform);
        var payload = _.template(' <head><link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=style_pdf%>"></head><body> <h1 class="titulo"> Hello World </h1></body>') 
        cordova.plugins.pdf.fromData(payload({css_file: style_pdf}),
          opts)
        .then(progressHide)
        .catch(progressHide);
```

The structure of my files is like this:

[image]

The documentation is as follows:
https://github.com/cesarvr/pdf-generator#howto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looking for `_` (lodash), so it can use its `template` function. You need to add that library to your project.

Comment: I find myself working with vuejs, how can I incorporate it?

Comment: @JG_GJ Check out the installation instructions on lodash.com, it can be done via npm or a script tag.

Comment: Thank you very much already worked, now I just have the problem that it does not find the css file, I don't know in which part of my project I should add it, if you could support me I would appreciate it. This is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57665118/why-css-file-is-not-defined-cordova-plugin-pdf

Comment: Glad you solved this one. I'm not familiar enough with Cordova to help with the other issue but someone should chime in. Cheers!